# Navigation Drawer and FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-navigation

I'm relatively new to android development. Basically, I got a Navigation Drawer. One of the menu will need to open FragmentActivity with viewpager.

here the displayview function

```
 /**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    LAST_DISPLAY_POSITION = position;

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestFragmentActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new MyAccountFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new TestFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new TestFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new TestFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

as you can see at Case 0, I just calling startactivity to open the view. How can I display the FragmentActivity with the Navigation Drawer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: you cant display a activity in the navigation drawer just.. just use fragment.. any reason for what you are doing?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin sorry for my broken english. i think you misunderstood my question. As you can see in the code, Case 1 until 5 will use TestFragment() which are fragments. However for Case 0, i want to use FragmentActivity because I use viewpager in the FragmentActivity

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have the same issue now

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, right now you might have written code for `NavigationDrawer` in your single activity say `DisplayFragmentsActivity` and you are going to another activity `TestFragmentActivity` which will surely make you write code for `NavigationDrawer` in that activity too plus you will need to manage all other things for selection of menu if you are handling.

So, I suggest move your code of `NavigationDrawer` from `DisplayFragmentsActivity` to a new `MasterFragmentActivity` and extend that activity to your `DisplayFragmentsActivity` and `TestFragmentActivity`. So now you will have the same drawer in your both the activities.

This will solve the problem.

Another suggestion you might look to avoid creating another activity, as you are using fragments try to use single activity only. try to find some replacement for `TestFragmentActivity`.

Comment: currently I only has 1 Navigation Drawer. My Navigation Drawer is under MainActivity. All display using fragment except Case 0 using FragmentActivity as I want to use ViewPager